# nil pointer warning on wsl start

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, troubleshooting

Good day, everyone!
After upgrade wsl from 1 to 2 I've started to recieve a warning on wsl start:

```
: nil pointer evaluating template.Data.Command
```

Any ideas what is that and how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance a lot! I've tried to find exactly this problem in Google - nothing found(((. In user profile folder file .wslconfig doesn't exists. I've tried to make one, no difference - I recieve this message with or without existance of this file. I recieve this message even without installed Linux distributives, so I think problem is in wsl itself, but reinstalling via enable/disable windows component Windows Subsystem for Linux takes no effect. My guess - error somewhere in config file or something, but where definately - I can't imagine… (((. In theory, this warning displayes only with wsl command (wsl or wsl --install, etc), and not affect something (as far I can see), but something is wrong about it and I still hope to fix this problem… Thanks again!

Comment: *"I recieve this message even without installed Linux distributives, so I think problem is in wsl itself"* - so it sounds like you should be asking on a Windows forum

Comment: Ok, I'll try… thanks